# how to perform a conditional rowsums by choosing the highest value of 2 columns

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I was looking for a way to sum values of entire rows while using the higher value between two specific columns.

for example,

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(0:20,5),
             b = sample(0:20,5),
             c = sample(0:20,5),
             d = sample(0:20,5),
             e = sample(0:20,5),
             f = sample(0:20,5),
             g = sample(0:20,5))
print(df)

   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
1 19 10  9 19 18 10 15
2 18 14 14 20  2  7 16
3  5  2 17  2 20 17  7
4 14 11  4  8 17  8 12
5 10 17  7  9  1 14  0
```

now what I wanted is calculate for each row

a+b+c+(whichever higher between d and e)+(whichever higher between f and g)

I'm familiar with rowSums, but I don't know how to add the above mentioned condition

thanks in advance

Comment: In baseR: `rowSums(df[, c("a", "b", "c")]) + with(df, pmax(d, e) + pmax(f, g))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pmax` to get the max value for the subset of columns per row and add with the rest

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(new = a + b + c + pmax(d, e) + pmax(f, g))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` method:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new := a + b + c + pmax(d, e) + pmax(f, g)]
```